# mysql time field conditions for expiration

Tags: mysql

I have table with auction lots:

```
mysql> desc lots;
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(10)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| account_id | int(10)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| item_id    | int(10)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| bid        | int(10)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| buyout     | int(10)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| leader     | int(13)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| left       | int(10)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

left - field in unix timestamp format like '1391143424'. This shows the timestamp after which the lot should be expired.

I need to develop efficient algorithm for:
-when customer click on SEARCH button, the result will show only non-expired lots
-once lot expired it should be automatically put into `completed_lots` table

I have some ideas, but want to verify if there is any better approaches:
1: add additional search criteria like:

```
 WHERE '$currtime' <= left;
```

2: setup some asynchronous tasks using crontab that will check `lots` table for expired lots every 5 minutes and move it to `completed_lots` table.

Are there any better ways? maybe using another mysql filed types for unix time, or create some mysql functions that will do that job automatically?

Comment: Change the datatype of `left` from `int(10` to `timestamp`. That way MySQL will let you use date-comparison functions with it directly.

Comment: Also, you don't want a separate `completed_lots` table, just add an `is_complete` boolean column. Or just treat `left <= NOW()` as an invarient this would obviates the need for a cron-job completely.

Comment: that's interesting idea, but my concern is the following:  I have ~100-150K records in lots table, and everyday people create ~200-300 new lots, if I will not move expired lots to `completed_lots` - then `lots` table can grow to outstanding sizes, that will cause degradation with search requests.

Comment: Tables with tens of millions of records can be efficiently accessed provided that one has adopted a suitable indexing strategy; tables larger than that can be efficiently accessed provided that one has adopted a suitable partitioning strategy.

Comment: you want to say that searching by `left` criteria on 100K rows table and on 5-10M rows table is not much difference for mysql engine? Only Indexes can make this similar, really?

Comment: That is correct.  MySQL implements indexes as [B-trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree), which can be searched in time that is logarithmic to their size.

Comment: @httpd Correct. Computers are *very* fast. And I have a database table with over 20 million rows (160GB on disk) and zero performance problems.